# How long does it take to mine redstone with a wooden pickaxe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have never mined redstone with a wooden pickaxe before.
How many seconds it takes to mine redstone with one?

Answer (score 6):

You can't get redstone with a wooden pickaxe. The only way to get redstone from a redstone ore is to mine it with an iron or a diamond pickaxe, as stated on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone):

> A single redstone ore will yield 4–5 redstone when mined with an **iron** or **diamond** pickaxe.

For the time needed to destroy the block if you were doing it with a wooden pickaxe, it would be 7,5 seconds. But then again, you wouldn't get any redstone from doing it.

You can see a comprehensive list of breakable blocks and time to break them [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe#Speed).

The data for Redstone is as follows:

[image]

The red background means the block will be destroyed without dropping any resources.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.***

If you want to mine Redstone Ore, you will need a pickaxe (or other tool if using mods) of the `Redstone level` or higher. `Redstone level` means that **you will need an Iron or Diamond Pickaxe**.

*Technically, you can mine the block with a Wooden Pick, but you will not gain any Redstone Dust from it. The Ore will be destroyed and it will take some time.

Comment: Will Gold not do it? Every answer has left it out.

Comment: Gold Pickaxe can't get Redstone.  See [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Pickaxe#Speed)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are able to, but I would say the time does not matter if you're aiming to obtain the redstone as breaking redstone ore with a wooden pickaxe will not drop any redstone. You will need an iron or diamond pickaxe to get a drop.

Answer (score -1):

It would take 7.5 seconds to mine a Redstone Ore block with a Wooden Pickaxe. However, you wont get any drops from it.

To obtain Redstone dust from Redstone Ore you need either an Iron Pickaxe or a Diamond Pickaxe.

Comment: This does not add anything to the the discussion, as these facts have already been stated in previous answers.